# Overloading operator delete with additional argument of size_t sz in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

The code below allows you to see size of variable being deleted:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct P {
    static void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
    {
        cout << "custom delete for size " << sz <<endl;
        delete (ptr); // ::operator delete(ptr) can also be used
    }
    static void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
    {
        cout << "custom delete for size " << sz <<endl;
        delete (ptr); // ::operator delete(ptr) can also be used
    }
};

int main()
{
    P* var1 = new P;
    delete var1;

    P* var2 = new P[10];
    delete[] var2;
}
```

Output:

```
custom delete for size 1
custom delete for size 14
```

My questions is:
Where does argument `std::size_t sz` get assigned value?

Comment: [Regarding `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301) and when you combine it [with `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4581301), you can cause some pretty impressive unforced errors. Best to just not use either and avoid unnecessary trainwrecks entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
Where does argument std::size_t sz get assigned value?
```

The compiler does that. The expression `delete var;` has two parts - first the destructor for `P` (if any) is called, and then `operator delete` is called with  parameters supplied by the compiler.

Despite their similar names, ["the delete operator"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) and ["`operator delete`"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) are two different things.

(And Bjarne has said that he is sorry to not have come up with better names).